# Magento2. Homepage Hot sellers

Tags: magento2, product, home-page

I want to get the all products and make changes in these product showing on the **homepage**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This products are shown as widget in home-page-block cms block.

It is Catalog Product list widget, so you can configure Number of Products to Display, template, and wich products to show.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.. I want make changes progmatically how to can I get these products??

Comment: What exactly changes do you want to do?design?

Answer (score 0):

You can do an override like this :

> app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList">
        <plugin name="module_widget_override" type="YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\Block\Product\MyOverridePlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/Plugin/Block/Product/MyOverridePlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\Block\Product;


class MyOverridePlugin
{
    die('IT WORKS')
}
```

If you want to modify the template , open the template path hints [LINK](https://magecomp.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-in-magento-2/) . And override the template that is displaying thoses products.

I think this is the template:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml

Make the logic in this section

```
<?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart): ?>
                                    <div class="product-item-actions">
                                        <?php if ($showCart): ?>
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getTypeInstance()->hasRequiredOptions($_item)): ?>
                                                        <button class="action tocart primary" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl":{"url":"<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <?php
                                                            $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
                                                            $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
                                                        ?>
                                                        <button class="action tocart primary" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $postData ?>' type="button" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php else: ?>
                                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks.. but what will I do to hide the "Add to Cart" on the Hot Sellers for the specific products

Comment: Updated my answer @AsadKhan

Comment: Actually I'm not getting the Layout of the HotSeller to override it

Comment: @AsadKhan follow this link for more info http://oshansideas.blogspot.com/2016/11/magento2-override-widget-template.html